# How to find out start of next day using Java

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

In my simple application, I am storing the timestamp into the database table programmatically by using `new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())`.

Now, I have one condition, where I have to store the onClick count for a particular day, and all onClick counts into two different columns.

So for that, I need to find out onClicks for today. So how can I find out if the time onclicks occur are today? I mean for say 1st August, I want all the onclick counts in one column and all previous onClick counts into another column.

***In simple words - storing clicks for today in one column and storing clicks till now in another column, so if today expires, I want to add clicks for today with total clicks and then make the today_clicks column count to 0 and then when there is new click on next day, store it in the today_clicks column by starting it with count 1***

How can I decide that? Which Java class should I use for that?

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous (at least for me).  I've tired my best to decipher it, I only hope it helps

Comment: Sorry if I could not put it in words properly, What I mean was storing clicks for today in one column and storing clicks till now in another column, so if today expires, I want to add clicks for today with total clicks and then when there is new click on next day, store it in the column by starting it with count 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to best store your data in your database.  You have decided to maintain a clicks-for-today column and a clicks-until-now column. (I may be off base on this, but it wasnt completely clear from the question)

I would suggest that you dont try to manipulate the data from column to column as you have described, but instead do so by maintaining click counts per day:

```
 date | count
------|-------
Jul 31| 10876
Aug  1| 15721
```

(where date is a in the db timestamp/date datatype)

How would this work?

At startup, you could then bring into memory all rows, and sum their counts to get a clicks-until-now value, if needed.

You then have special handling for today's row, where you update the appropriate context with the clicks-for-today value.

To determine whether you've passed a day threshold, you could simply:

1. maintain a Calendar instance for 'today' (call it `todayCal`)
2. generate a new Calendar each time you record a click (call it `clickCal`)
3. test Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR from `todayCal` and `clickCal`
4. if you identify a day roll, you persist the clicks-for-today in the db and initialized a new clicks-for-today.
5. if you are maintaining total click count in memory, you can do the math at this point.

Comment: I am not sure my application design will permit that, how about storing last click date/time along and when the next click happens (say after 24hrs so next day) comparing it with last click date/time to find out if it is today or not , so storing today's click into today_click column and before doing that moving count of the total_click = today_click   + total_clicks and making today_click = 0;

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if that is what are you after. To get start of next day you can use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
public static Date nextDayStart(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    return cal.getTime();
}
```

To get tomorrow:

```
Date tomorrow = nextDayStart(new Date());
```

To get `Timestamp` from `Date`:

```
Timestamp s = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not sure what you meant here. I am not looking to get nextday, maybe you can read the question again, I have highlighted my gist of question

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest taking a look at [Joda Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Java).

Second, I'd take a look at `Calendar`:

```
Calendar lower = Calendar.getInstance();
lower.setTime(new Date());
lower.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
lower.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
lower.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
lower.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Calendar upper = Calendar.getInstance();
upper.setTime(new Date());
upper.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
upper.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
upper.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
upper.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 99);

Date clickTime = new Date(timeInMillis);
if (clickTime.after(lower.getTime()) && clickTime.before(upper.getTime())) {
    // Is today
}
```

Comment: compilation err at lower and upper

Comment: @AndyKu sorry, typing from memory :P